# SSAS How to scope a calculated member measure to a number of specific members?

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I'm trying to create a calculated member measure for a subset of a group of locations. All other members should be null. I can limit the scope but then in the client (excel in this case) the measure does not present the grand total ([Group].[Group].[All]).

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Calculated Measure]
 AS (
     Null
    ),
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measures].[Places] } 
,VISIBLE = 1 ,    ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Locations';

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SCOPE ({([Group].[Group].&[location 1]),
        ([Group].[Group].&[location 2]),  
        ([Group].[Group].&[location 3]),
        ([Group].[Group].&[location 4]),
        ([Group].[Group].&[location 5])
        }, [Measures].[Calculated Measure]);

// Location Calculations 

THIS = (
      [Measures].[Adjusted Dollars] - [Measures].[Adjusted Dollars by Component] + [Measures].[Adjusted OS Dollars]
    ); 

END SCOPE;
```

It's as though the [Group].[Group].[All] member is outside of the scope so it won't aggregate the rest of the members. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched high and low for this answer. After reading the above suggestion, I came up with this:

1. Calculate the measure in a column in the source view table 

   `(isnull(a,0) - isnull(b,0)) + isnull(c,0) = x`
2. Add the unfiltered calculated column (x) to the dsv
3. Create a named calculation in the dsv that uses a case statement to filter the original calc measure 
   `CASE WHEN location IN ( 1,2,3)`
   `THEN x`
   `ELSE NULL`
   `END`
4. Add the named calculation as measure

I choose to do it this way to capture the measure unfiltered first then, if another filter needs to be added or one needs to be taken off, I can do so without messing with the views again. I just add the new member to filter by to my named calculation case statement. I tried to insert the calculation directly into a named calculation in the dsv that filtered it as well but the calculation produced the incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is applied after all calculations already happened. You can get around this by adding `Root([Time])` to the scope, assuming your time dimension is named `[Time]`. And if you want to aggregate across more dimensions, you would have to add them all to the `SCOPE`.

In most cases when you have a calculation that you want too do before aggregation it is more easy to define the calculation e. g. in the DSV, e. g. with an expression like

```
CASE WHEN group_location in(1, 2, 3, 4) THEN
          Adjusted_dollars - adjusted_dollars_by_comp + adjusted_os_dollars
     ELSE NULL
END
```

and just make a standard aggregatable measure from it.

Comment: I see what you're saying about the aggregation happening before the calc. I'm not sure how I'd include the Time dimension (Time Intelligence in my case) in the scope and how that would solve my problem. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'd just like to understand how that would fix it.

Comment: @Vin If you use a standard measure, then aggregation would be done the standard way (summing in most cases).